# One to many relationship - Only return matches in children

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a one to many relationship between a student table and a courses table. I wanted to return all students that have courses that match a certain criteria at the moment I have this

```
.Context.Users.Where(it => 
                        it.Category.Description == "Student" &&
                        it.Courses.All(p => p.Submitted == true && p.StatusId == null) && 
                        it.Courses.Count > 0);
```

Now this works fine; if I remove "it.Courses.Count > 0 " then I get matching Students that have no courses. Is there a better way of doing this without the Count?

Thanks,

Dale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve it a little bit by replacing `it.Courses.Count > 0` by

```
it.Courses.Any()
```

which asks if the collection has "any" element (at least one) and which translates to `EXISTS` in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will use this method. It's always a little strange trying to convert what you would do in T-SQL to Linq

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this

```
Context.Users.Where(it => 
                        it.Category.Description == "Student" &&
                        it.Courses.Any(p => p.Submitted == true && p.StatusId == null))
```

Comment: This would also return students which have courses not submitted (as long as they have any other course submitted). It's another query with a different result.